# How can i show my android app apk file original size in google play?

Tags: android, google-play, apk, android-build

I developed an android application with some HQ drawables. I used different drawables for different resolutions like xhdpi,hdpi,mdpi,ldpi. So my final apk file size is increased and that is 5.8MB. I uploaded that apk file into android market it is showing as 12MB size. And i installed the same apk in HTC Sprint 4G devices and navigate to app info in setting. There app size is showing as 7.8MB. I am not getting that is the reason for showing wrong apk size.Could any body advice me is there any problem with my signing of application. Advice me is there any  possible faults and their solutions.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you enable copy protection for your `apk`, while uploading it to the market, then you will require more space on the device to install this copy-protected `apk`. It is mentioned clearly in the app-details section of developer console, under 'Publishing options':
[image]

Comment: Yes exactly you are right.That option is on for my application. Can you say if we off the copy protection what will the problem

Comment: As per the android-dev-console, Copy protection *may* help prevent applications from being copied from a device. If you turn this feature OFF then your app can/(may) be copied from the device and put into some other device.

Comment: so Copy protection prevents the copying apk from device. And user who installed for google play can only use the application.This is like secure mechanism for android application right?